# My mysql stored procedure row_count() inside another stored Procedure always returns zero

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Mysql ROW_COUNT() returns zero even if the update changes the database. I have  a Stored Procedure A which call's another Stored Procedure B which has a Update Statement. I also used set AUTOCOMMIT =0 and start transaction in stored procedure A.

In procedure A

```
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
SET done = 1;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION,sqlwarning
BEGIN

GET CURRENT DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
set Message = concat(errno , msg);
ROLLBACK;
END;    
set autocommit = 0 ;
start transaction;


call test_update(@Inv_Header_gid,@Message1);                                                                                        

select @Message1 into @out_SOINV_Msg;

if @out_SOINV_Msg <> 'SUCCESS' then

set Message = concat('Error On SOInvoice Update ',@out_SOINV_Msg);

rollback;

leave sp_DispatchProcess_Set;

end if;

if @out_SOINV_Msg = 'SUCCESS' then                                                                              

set Message = 'SUCCESS';

end if;
```

In Procedure B

```
declare Query_Updatee varchar(1000);
declare update_countt int;

set INV_Header_Gid = '999';
set  Query_Updatee= Concat('Update gal_mst_tdealerprice set dealerprice_status = ''no136jj''

where dealerprice_gid = ',INV_Header_Gid,'');



         set @Query_Updatee = Query_Updatee;

         PREPARE stmtr FROM @Query_Updatee;
         EXECUTE stmtr;  
         set update_countt =  (select ROW_COUNT());

         select found_rows();

         DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtr;                     

         if update_countt > 0 then
            set Messagee = 'SUCCESS';
         else 
            set Messagee ='FAILZrtttt';
            select update_countt;
            rollback;
```

Comment: Found_rows() apply to selects, not to updates, so do not be surprised if it has a different return value as row_count(). What is the real question here?

Comment: I mean the ROW_COUNT() not return 1 even if the changes in the Row.

Comment: This problem arises only when calling inside the another stored procedure

Comment: Change the update statement from a prepared statement to an inline one. Prepared statements are executed in a different scope and this may interfere with row_count().

Comment: The Inline Statement also not returns 1.

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=becbd72b62169192d5cb2afa886c4688).